# Issue in running an update query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a relational access database and I want to update a table based on another table. You can see relations in the picture[image: Query Picture]. SQL statement is as bellow. When I try to update I face "Your query does not include the specified expression "TRX900" as part of an aggregate function."

But When I try to see in datasheet view mode, it is OK. Your support is appreciated.

```
Update
  (
    (
        Sites INNER JOIN Cells ON Sites.ID = Cells.SiteID
    ) INNER JOIN Cells_2G ON Cells.ID = Cells_2G.[Cell ID] 
  ) ,
  ImportedTRX INNER JOIN ActiveStatus ON ImportedTRX.[Active Status] = ActiveStatus.Status
Set
  Cells_2G.TRX900=Sum( IIF ( ImportedTRX.Frequency <=124 , 1,0 )  )
  , 
  Cells_2G.TRX1800=Sum( IIF ( ImportedTRX.Frequency >=512 , 1,0 )  )
WHERE 
  (
    ImportedTRX.[cell name]=[Sites].[SiteID] & [Cells].[Cell_Order]
    AND 
    ActiveStatus.YesNo=True
  )
;
```

Sites table sample:

```
-----------------------
|    ID      | SiteID |
-----------------------
|     1      | T4000X |
-----------------------
```

Cells table sample:

```
------------------------------------
|    ID      | SiteID | Cell_Order |
------------------------------------
|     1      |    1   | A          |
|     2      |    1   | B          |
|     3      |    1   | C          |
------------------------------------
```

Cell_2G sample table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|    ID      | CellID | Expected TRX900 | Expected TRX1800 |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |    1   |        1        |        2         |
|     2      |    2   |        2        |        1         |
|     3      |    3   |        2        |        3         |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

ImportedTRX table sample

```
-------------------------
| Cell Name | Frequency |
-------------------------
|  T4000XA  | 800       |
|  T4000XA  | 801       |
|  T4000XA  | 22        |
|  T4000XB  | 4         |
|  T4000XB  | 33        |
|  T4000XB  | 860       |
|  T4000XC  | 20        |
|  T4000XC  | 21        |
|  T4000XC  | 840       |
|  T4000XC  | 841       |
|  T4000XC  | 842       |
-------------------------
```

Comment: You aren't going to get this query working. You can avoid this issue by adding `GROUP BY TRX900, TRX1800` at the bottom, but then you will get errors because your recordset isn't updateable, which is the main problem. To avoid that you'd have to rewrite your whole query to use domain aggregates instead of joins, and without sample data and expected output we can't do that for you.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I put a little sample in the following path: 
  
 http://s8.picofile.com/file/8338728400/Sample_accdb.html     Also I put two columns with name "Expected TRX900" and "expected TRX1800" as expected results in the "Cells_2G" table. your help appreciated. My porpose is to update "Cells_2G" table based on "importedTRX" table. I want to count number of frequencies for each corresponding cells_2G record

Comment: Sorry, I don't download Access databases from untrusted sources. See [Share a table on Stack Overflow for easy import into MS Access](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359195/7296893) for how to share tables on SO.

Comment: Dear Erik. I did edit my question, and added sample tables.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this problem:

1. Create 2 queries, 1 preparing the result and 1 executing the update, where the
2. Parse using VBA.

I'm going to share the second approach.

The first query is essentially your current query converted to a `SELECT` query, only the table you're updating has been removed

**Query Query1:**

```
SELECT
  Sum( IIF ( ImportedTRX.Frequency <=124 , 1,0 )  ) As TRX900
  , 
  Sum( IIF ( ImportedTRX.Frequency >=512 , 1,0 )  ) As TRX1800,
  Cells.ID

FROM
    (
        Sites INNER JOIN Cells ON Sites.ID = Cells.SiteID
    ),
  ImportedTRX INNER JOIN ActiveStatus ON ImportedTRX.[Active Status] = ActiveStatus.Status
WHERE 
  (
    ImportedTRX.[cell name]=[Sites].[SiteID] & [Cells].[Cell_Order]
    AND 
    ActiveStatus.YesNo=True
  )
GROUP BY
  Cells.ID
;
```

Then, we're going to update the table using `DLookUp` and querying from that query:

**Query Query2:**

```
UPDATE Cells_2G 
SET
Cells_2G.TRX900= DLookUp("TRX900", "Query1", "ID = " & [Cell ID]),
Cells_2G.TRX1800= DLookUp("TRX1800", "Query1", "ID = " & [Cell ID])
```

This produces the desired result, though you haven't included the `ActiveStatus` table so I couldn't include that in testing.

Unfortunately, the statement is too complex for me to write into a single update query, so this two-step approach is the best non-VBA solution I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you very much Erik, Your hint and support, helped me a lot. I'll use the sql in my VBA.  However your mentioned solution take so much time to run in my database. After some try, I found a single query solution that is run faster, and I like to share with you. but I don't know how to share in comment. Should I answer to my questin?

Comment: If it solves your problem, you can share it as an answer. If you want to ask further questions about it, you can either ask a new question, or edit it into your question if your question won't substantially change.

Answer (score 0):

After some try I used following code, but it is slow yet.

```
UPDATE 
  ImportedTRX, 
  (
    Sites INNER JOIN Cells ON Sites.ID=Cells.SiteID
  ) INNER JOIN Cells_2G ON Cells.ID= cells_2G.[Cell ID] 
SET 
  Cells_2G.TRX900 = DSUM("IIF(Frequency<=124,1,0)", "ImportedTRX", "[Cell Name]='"& Sites.SiteID & Cells.Cell_Order & "'")
  , 
  Cells_2G.TRX1800 = DSUM("IIF(Frequency>=512,1,0)", "ImportedTRX", "[Cell Name]='"& Sites.SiteID & Cells.Cell_Order & "'")
WHERE 
  (
    ImportedTRX.[Cell Name]=Sites.[SiteID] & Cells.[Cell_Order]
  );
```